# Activeadmin: Customize form

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails-3, activeadmin

In my active admin form I'm retrieving multiple users with email, name, mobile attribute. I want to display this in table format like email, name, mobile as indexes.

```
     f.input :user_ids, :label => "Users", 
  :multiple => true,  collection: @user.collect{|u| [[u.email, u.name, u.mobile].to_s.gsub('"',""), u.id]}, 
  :required => true, :input_html => { :class => "users_checkboxes", :size => 20
```

**Ex:**
Above code display the following:

[rr@example.com,Robert,78789799]

[avrtyjoserc@example.com,Kamal,99098889]

I want to display in proper order like space between email, name and mobile, so that make appearance better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `join` to display the user information in a better way, for example:

```
:multiple => true,  collection: @user.collect{|u| [[u.email, u.name, u.mobile].join(" - "), u.id]}
```

Then the result will be displayed like this:

```
rr@gmail.com - Robert - 78789799
```

Just substitute the dash with anything you prefer.